# Can't connect Putty to VirutalBox VM

Tags: linux, rhel, virtual-machine, putty

This is an issue I encounter while following the instructions laid out in [Asghar Ghori's RHSCA training book for RHEL 8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1775062147).  I am to setup a RHEL virtual machine with VirtualBox and connect Putty to it, but when I do this I get a connection timeout.  When discussing VM setup in VirtualBox on page 14, "You may have to... attach the network adapter to Bridge Adapter under Network for bi-directional communication with the Windows host and the Internet."

My RHEL-VM1 settings are shown below.  I changed the Network Adapter 1 from NAT to Bridged.
[image]

While giving instructions on RHEL installation on page 24, "Go to IPv4 Settings and choose Manual from the drop-down list against Method.  Click ADD and enter address 192.168.0.110, netmask 24, and gateway 192.168.0.1."

As I have already completed installation, I can show the RHEL VM Network settings below.
[image]

As per the continued instructions on page 32, I try to use Putty on the host machine to connect to the RHEL VM with these settings:
[image]

The result is a Connection timeout.
[image]

What have I done wrong?

---

As requested, the results of route print in the Windows host.

```
C:\Users\Sam>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
  9...a8 a1 59 67 74 a4 ......Killer E3100G 2.5 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
 15...0a 00 27 00 00 0f ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
 16...00 ff 8c 98 24 ac ......Private Internet Access Network Adapter
 19...84 1b 77 7d 7d 15 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 12...86 1b 77 7d 7d 14 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 20...84 1b 77 7d 7d 14 ......Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX1650x 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (200NGW)
 13...84 1b 77 7d 7d 18 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1       10.0.0.118     25
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.0.0.118    281
       10.0.0.118  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.0.118    281
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.0.118    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.0.0.118    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.0.118    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  9    281 ::/0                     fe80::10:18ff:fe41:84aa
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  9    281 2601:446:480:db60::/64   On-link
  9    281 2601:446:480:db60::1e0b/128
                                    On-link
  9    281 2601:446:480:db60:59c8:ac69:ffc7:e87f/128
                                    On-link
  9    281 2601:446:480:db60:85d7:342d:e5e5:4049/128
                                    On-link
 15    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 15    281 fe80::856a:3f4f:d390:4a0e/128
                                    On-link
  9    281 fe80::85d7:342d:e5e5:4049/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 15    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
  9    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Results of ipconfig/all on Windows host:

```
C:\Users\Sam>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-6KK2N8R
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : hsd1.mn.comcast.net

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.mn.comcast.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Killer E3100G 2.5 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A8-A1-59-67-74-A4
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2601:446:480:db60::1e0b(Preferred)
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, June 22, 2022 1:33:08 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, July 8, 2022 3:42:39 AM
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2601:446:480:db60:85d7:342d:e5e5:4049(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2601:446:480:db60:59c8:ac69:ffc7:e87f(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::85d7:342d:e5e5:4049%9(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.118(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, June 22, 2022 1:33:07 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, July 8, 2022 6:33:14 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::10:18ff:fe41:84aa%9
                                       10.0.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 346595673
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-28-03-01-9E-A8-A1-59-67-74-A4
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:558:feed::1
                                       2001:558:feed::2
                                       75.75.75.75
                                       75.75.76.76
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-0F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::856a:3f4f:d390:4a0e%15(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 772407335
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-28-03-01-9E-A8-A1-59-67-74-A4
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Private Internet Access Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-8C-98-24-AC
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 84-1B-77-7D-7D-15
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 86-1B-77-7D-7D-14
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.mn.comcast.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX1650x 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (200NGW)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 84-1B-77-7D-7D-14
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 84-1B-77-7D-7D-18
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

ip address on RHEL VM terminal:
[image]

Comment: What is the IP of your host? Also check if there is any firewall blocking your connection.

Comment: How many physical machines are involved - just one machine running Windows with redhat in the virtualbox? What is the **windows** network configuration (show us the output of running "route print" as long as it is less than 15 lines long)?

Comment: I wasn't sure which ip address would be most useful, so I added the output of ipconfig/all from the Windows host.

Comment: If you add @icarus as part of your comment then stack exchange will notify me. This might mean you get a faster response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output of the network commands it appears that your windows machine is using 10.0.0.0/24 for the network, rather than 192.168.0.0/24 that your guide is assuming. If you change the 192.168.0.110 to 10.0.0.110 everywhere (the VM nerwork config and the putty command) then this should enable the connection.

### Background

The network routing tables on the **windows** side of the world are set tp send packets that you hope to get to your redhat VM to the router and thence to comcast,which correctly discards them as they are from RFC1918 reserved networks. Giving your VM an address on your LAN will let the packets go to the VM.

Comment: I am having difficulty changing the RHEL VM IP with its desktop UI.  It seems to continually revert back to previous settings.  If I am to use the terminal to do this, would this be the correct command:  `ifconfig enp0s3 10.0.0.110/24`

Comment: I have tried the command in the previous comment.  It did seem to change the IP for enp0s3, but Putty still can't connect with this 10.0.0.110 address.

Comment: You can try using 192.168.56.x everywhere in place of 10.0.0.x. This is the other network that appears to be configured.

Comment: In the RHL VM terminal I set the IP address with `ifconfig enp0s3 192.168.56.110/24` and confirmed the change with `ip a`.  I then tried to connect with Putty using 192.168.56.110.  It responded with the same "Network error: Connection time out".

Comment: What is the output of "ip route" inside the VM? Can you answer the question about how many machines you are using?

Comment: IP route:
`default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100 \n
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.110 metric 100 \n
192.168.0.1 dev enp0s3 proto static scope link metric 100 \n
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown`
The IP's may have changed based on my setting experiments with ifconfig enp0s3.  I tried to fix formatting with newline characters, but that doesn't seem to work in comments.

Comment: To your question about how many machines am I using, there may be an unknown number of machines connected to my router, but as far as the machines in question, it is really only my desktop with this one RHL VM.

Comment: With Putty I've just had a successful login using 10.0.0.110.  I'm not yet sure why it worked now and didn't work before.  I'm not sure what has changed to make it work.

Comment: I think that, upon booting, the RHL VM always reverts back to 10.0.0.110, and if this is changed to any value including back to 10.0.0.110, it doesn't work.  If it is left alone and not changed after booting, 10.0.0.110 will work.

Comment: Glad it is working. If you are happy with the answer and think it is the best you are going to get then you can "accept" the answer. This helps future users of the site evaluate the answers.

Comment: I just wish there was more available, like "The reason why Ghori set the address to 192.168.0.110/24 was __, and if you set the address to 10.0.0.110 you might run into __ problem later.  The address 10.0.0.110 is significant for VirtualBox because it is used inside its own private network, and therefore __.  The reason the VM defaults to this address is __.  The reason it doesn't work when it is changed is __."  I don't feel I know enough to be able to answer these questions though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation points to ask as a comment that is why I am writing this as answer. As long as the ssh server is running in the redhat virtual machine, one thing that could be wrong is the manual ip address you are setting up in redhat. You need to see the netmask and ip address of your physical machine and set up accordingly. If your ip address is something like 192.168.1.xxx you should add an ip address of 192.168.1.yyy in your vm. Otherwise you should add an appropriate route from your network to 192.168.0.0/24.